# Is it possible to make apex:input "locale aware"?

Tags: date, html5, locale

I want to use the fairly new input types that HTML5 defines. In Salesforce, the different types are:
`date, datetime, datetime-local, month, week, time, email, number, range, search, tel, text, and url`. When used with `doctype="html5"`, an input field of type date (`<apex:input type"date"/>`) looks like the following:

[image]

Is it possible to make this input, somehow "locale aware"? i.e.: instead of `mm/dd/yyyy` for example `dd.mm.yyyy` (Finnish date locale).

Thanks!

Comment: The locale the browser/OS drives the format for <input type="date"/> whereas Salesforce carries a locale on each User object. Is relying on the client having their browser/OS set appropriately sufficient for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format

What is said there is that the date is formatted following the User's locale settings in the browser. No way to override.

You may be be able to use the HTML5 standard date input field to *capture* the date from the User, and use another field to *show* the User chosen date. A bit tricky and requires Javascript, but that's it.

Comment: Thanks!, no need to override, just to be locale aware. So if the input depends on the browser's locale that is enough.