# Date and Number locale problem on html5 input type=date/number

Tags: date, inputfield, html5, locale

### Question

Is there any chance to send data in generic date format (`yyyy-mm-dd`) in standard save method?

I need to user `apex:input type="date"` (or number).  But Salesforce save method is not validating the value on save when the browser locale is distinct of the user locale.

**For instance:**

When user has `dd/mm/YYYY` as salesforce user date locale, but `YYYY-mm-dd` as browser date locale. I'm getting the **invalid Date error**.

I've searched many questions [like this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55479/is-it-possible-to-make-apexinput-locale-aware). But I can't figure out how to use the `input type="date"` without the locale issue.

Is there any why to force the input value in javascript? Like creating a hidden input and transform the date value to a generic format or something like that ?

The same is happening  with `type=number.`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, SF stores a Date value as a DateTime in GMT which is what allow them to convert it to the user locale. Apex has a `dateGMT()` method to return the date based on the GMT time. It also has `dayGMT()` ect. I don't know if there's a JS equivalent, but perhaps creating a function that submits the Date in GMT *might* solve your issue.

Comment: Your only real choice is going to be something along the lines of submitting the dates in ISO 8601 format via an actionFunction to update the controller's values and force a rerender of the fields to the expected format. I'd probably use hidden fields to bind to the actual values to reduce user confusion when the date changes from their browser-displayed version to whatever salesforce.com is expecting based on their user locale.